# Error creating index on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I am using elasticsearch: stable 1.2.1, HEAD. It was installed with 'brew'.
I am also able to start it without any problems.

However when I create an index I got this exception:

```
[2014-07-11 13:40:33,300][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [N'astirh] [x_application_item_development] failed to create
org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexCreationException: [x_application_item_development] failed to create index
  at org.elasticsearch.indices.InternalIndicesService.createIndex(InternalIndicesService.java:302)
  at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:343)
  at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:309)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:134)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider.createMethodMapping(FactoryProvider.java:214)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider.newFactory(FactoryProvider.java:151)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider.newFactory(FactoryProvider.java:146)
  at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisModule.configure(AnalysisModule.java:274)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:60)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:204)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:85)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:130)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:99)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:131)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createChildInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:69)
  at org.elasticsearch.indices.InternalIndicesService.createIndex(InternalIndicesService.java:298)
  ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  ... 21 more
[2014-07-11 13:40:33,506][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [N'astirh] [x_application_item_development] failed to create
org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexCreationException: [x_application_item_development] failed to create index
  at org.elasticsearch.indices.InternalIndicesService.createIndex(InternalIndicesService.java:302)
  at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:343)
  at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:309)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:134)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider.createMethodMapping(FactoryProvider.java:214)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider.newFactory(FactoryProvider.java:151)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider.newFactory(FactoryProvider.java:146)
  at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisModule.configure(AnalysisModule.java:274)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:60)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:204)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:85)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:130)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:99)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:131)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createChildInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:69)
  at org.elasticsearch.indices.InternalIndicesService.createIndex(InternalIndicesService.java:298)
  ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  ... 21 more
```

This is the class path:

```
:/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.2.1/libexec/elasticsearch-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.2.1/libexec/*:/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.2.1/libexec/sigar/*
```

I downloaded the latest stable (1.2.2 there is version difference) from the elastic search site. And I started manually... The class path contains the same number of items (only the path prefix is different):
:/Users/boti/Downloads/elasticsearch-1.2.2/lib/elasticsearch-1.2.2.jar:/Users/boti/Downloads/elasticsearch-1.2.2/lib/*:/Users/boti/Downloads/elasticsearch-1.2.2/lib/sigar/*

In the manually installed version everything works...

Is this a brew recipe problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a brew recipe problem.

Then error you're getting about a missing class means there's something fundamentally wrong in the way the application is started. That or files are actually missing.

Either way it's a problem with your startup script that brew is using or the files brew downloaded for you.